# Javascript not displaying what i would expect

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having a little trouble with Javascript/php/html. I have written this code below to display "GetM"  if the time is > 480 seconds this seems to work great when there is just one instance of this. However, I have 14 blocks and any other blocks do not show their `GetM` values. Below is an image of what U mean by "blocks". The value for `GetM` on the first block is the percentage

[image: what I mean by blocks]

```
<div id ="ZL01001Percent" class="BottomboxPercent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var time = <?php echo $machine1->data(); ?>;
        var M = <?php echo $machine1->GetM(); ?>;
        var P = M.toFixed(1);

        if (time > 480) {
            document.write(P * 100 + '%');
        } 
    </script>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I can't see how do you expect this to be answered.

Comment: I can't even see what your problem is

Comment: Just debug the code in the chrome dev tools. My guess is that you are overwriting the global variables you are assigning if I understand how you have these "blocks" set up.

Comment: What is an expected value for `$machine1->data()`? For `$machine1->GetM()`? And you say you have 14 blocks, but you've only posted one. We can only help you as much as you help us.

Comment: why don't you write that block of code into a function and just call the function call. Then all vars that are set will be destroyed once the function returns, this would prevent problems when having the same code and vars repeated.

Comment: Please consider using punctuation in your text. This would make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you create a JS Object representation of your data. If you create a PHP array, you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate

```
var machines = <?PHP echo json_encode($myValues); ?>
```

which should result in

```
var machines = { 
  ZL01001: { time:500, M : 733},
  ZL01002: { time:600, M : 556}
}
```

and then you can do

```
window.onload=function() {
  for (var m in machines) {
    var machine = machines[m];
    document.getElementById(m+"Percent").innerHTML=machine.time>480?(machine.M.toFixed(1)*100)+"%":"";
  }
}
```